# How to see possible combinations of a given number in python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

in Python I wanting see all the possible combination's of a number, but limiting to 0's and 1's...

So for example the result of some loop would be:

```
0000
0001
0011
0111
1111
1000
and so on.
```

What python algorithm would best suite this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example is in the [`itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for i in itertools.product(range(2), repeat=4):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for the answers. Turns out what I was looking was a Gray Code. Gray code after Frank Gray, is a binary numeral system where two successive values differ in only one bit. WikiPedia

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(n):
   if n==1:
       return ['0', '1']
   tmp = f(n-1)
   return ['0'+v for v in tmp] + ['1'+v for v in tmp]

>>> f(4)
['0000',
'0001',
'0010',
'0011',
'0100',
'0101',
'0110',
'0111',
'1000',
'1001',
'1010',
'1011',
'1100',
'1101',
'1110',
'1111']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for k-combinations. Check [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/190465/) out.

The function you want to look at is xcombinations:

```
def xcombinations(items, n):
    if n==0: yield []
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(items)):
            for cc in xcombinations(items[:i]+items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, lots of info on generators and combinations that I needed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

See the [product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) generator.

> This module implements a number of iterator building blocks inspired
>   by constructs from APL, Haskell, and SML. Each has been recast in a
>   form suitable for Python.
>
> The module standardizes a core set of fast, memory efficient tools
>   that are useful by themselves or in combination. Together, they form
>   an “iterator algebra” making it possible to construct specialized
>   tools succinctly and efficiently in pure Python

.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_all_combinations(max_value):
    width = len('{0:0b}'.format(max_value))
    format_string = '{0:0%db}' % width
    for i in xrange(max_value):
        print format_string.format(i)
```